# ElasticSearch highlights after stripping HTML tags

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm building an Elastic Search index on ES 2.3.3 and I've defined the following field to have one subfield in the following way

```
"properties": {
        "content": {
            "type": "string",
            "index_options": "offsets",
            "store": "yes",
            "fields": {
                "base": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "base_analyzer"
                },
            }
}
```

I've defined `base_analyzer` in settings so that the HTML content is stripped

```
"base_analyzer":
                {
                    "tokenizer":    "standard",
                    "char_filter":  [ "html_strip"]
                }
```

What I would like to do is to perform a search and highlight the search terms as well on `content.base` (the `content` field stripped out of the HTML tags) and I'm doing that in the following way

```
"query":  {
           {"match": {"content.base": {"query": "this is what I'm searching"}}},
            },
            "highlight": {
              "fields": {
               "content.base": {}
              }
            }
```

The problem is if I use the following query in `_search` I still get the HTML tags in the highlighted fields. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Because the highlighting is done on the actual `_source` or the stored data, if `store: true`, which means the original input. The analyzer is only building the inverted index with terms, and highlighting doesn't use that.

Comment: thanks @AndreiStefan, but if I want to store the `content.base` field, is it enough to add `"store":"yes"` in that subfield? Would that work with the highlighting as well? Or is there a way to add `content.base` to the `_source`?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use stored fields or _source. It will not work with highlighting. This is how highlighting works and you cannot change it. The only thing you can do is stripping the html before indexing.

Comment: thanks for clarifying this! Too bad highlighting has that limitation. I guess I just have to re-index my documents and strip the HTML before.

Comment: @AndreiStefan even if `store: true` is the search going to be performed in the field stripped of the HTML, right?

Comment: Yes. By default, fields are not stored.

Answer (score 1):

Now if you want to completely strip out the html prior to indexing and storing the content as is, you can use the mapper attachment plugin - in which when you define the mapping, you can categorize the content_type to be "html." **You will be able to highlight without the html tags.**

The mapper attachment is useful for many things especially if you are handling multiple document types, but most notably - I believe just using this for the purpose of stripping out the html tags is sufficient enough (which you cannot do with the html_strip char filter).

Just a forewarning though - NONE of the html tags will be stored. So if you do need those tags somehow, I would suggest defining another field to store the original content. Another note: You cannot specify multifields for mapper attachment documents, so you would need to store that outside of the mapper attachment document. See my working example below.

You'll need to result in this mapping:

```
{
  "html5-es" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "document" : {
        "properties" : {
          "delete" : {
            "type" : "boolean"
          },
          "file" : {
            "type" : "attachment",
            "fields" : {
              "content" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "store" : true,
                "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets",
                "analyzer" : "autocomplete"
              },
              "author" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "store" : true,
                "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets"
              },
              "title" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "store" : true,
                "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets",
                "analyzer" : "autocomplete"
              },
              "name" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "date" : {
                "type" : "date",
               "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
              },
              "keywords" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "content_type" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
          "content_length" : {
                "type" : "integer"
              },
              "language" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "hash_id" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "path" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "raw_content" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "store" : true,
            "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets",
            "analyzer" : "raw"
          },
          "title" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : { //insert your own settings here },
    "warmers" : { }
  }
}
```

Such that in NEST, I will assemble the content as such:

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
attachment.Content =   Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes("path/to/document"));
attachment.ContentType = "html";

Document document = new Document();
document.File = attachment;
document.RawContent = InsertRawContentFromString(originalText);
```

I have tested this in Sense - results are as follows:

```
"file": {
    "_content": "PGh0bWwgeG1sbnM6TWFkQ2FwPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3Lm1hZGNhcHNvZnR3YXJlLmNvbS9TY2hlbWFzL01hZENhcC54c2QiPg0KICA8aGVhZCAvPg0KICA8Ym9keT4NCiAgICA8aDE+VG9waWMxMDwvaDE+DQogICAgPHA+RGVsZXRlIHRoaXMgdGV4dCBhbmQgcmVwbGFjZSBpdCB3aXRoIHlvdXIgb3duIGNvbnRlbnQuIENoZWNrIHlvdXIgbWFpbGJveC48L3A+DQogICAgPHA+wqA8L3A+DQogICAgPHA+YXNkZjwvcD4NCiAgICA8cD7CoDwvcD4NCiAgICA8cD4xMDwvcD4NCiAgICA8cD7CoDwvcD4NCiAgICA8cD5MYXZlbmRlci48L3A+DQogICAgPHA+wqA8L3A+DQogICAgPHA+MTAvNiAxMjowMzwvcD4NCiAgICA8cD7CoDwvcD4NCiAgICA8cD41IDA5PC9wPg0KICAgIDxwPsKgPC9wPg0KICAgIDxwPjExIDQ3PC9wPg0KICAgIDxwPsKgPC9wPg0KICAgIDxwPkhhbGxvd2VlbiBpcyBpbiBPY3RvYmVyLjwvcD4NCiAgICA8cD7CoDwvcD4NCiAgICA8cD5qb2c8L3A+DQogIDwvYm9keT4NCjwvaHRtbD4=",
    "_content_length": 0,
    "_content_type": "html",
    "_date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "_title": "Topic10"
},
"delete": false,
"raw_content": "<h1>Topic10</h1><p>Delete this text and replace it with your own content. Check your mailbox.</p><p> </p><p>asdf</p><p> </p><p>10</p><p> </p><p>Lavender.</p><p> </p><p>10/6 12:03</p><p> </p><p>5 09</p><p> </p><p>11 47</p><p> </p><p>Halloween is in October.</p><p> </p><p>jog</p>"
},
"highlight": {
"file.content": [
    "\n    <em>Topic10</em>\n\n    Delete this text and replace it with your own content. Check your mailbox.\n\n     \n\n    asdf\n\n     \n\n    10\n\n     \n\n    Lavender.\n\n     \n\n    10/6 12:03\n\n     \n\n    5 09\n\n     \n\n    11 47\n\n     \n\n    Halloween is in October.\n\n     \n\n    jog\n\n  "
    ]
}
```